# How to add rows to an existing table using Docx4J

Tags: java, excel, docx4j

I have an existing Workbook with a Sheet that has a table ('table' refers to the Insert Table feature of the Excel UI with column headers and filter arrows, etc). I am having trouble determining which classes to use to edit existing rows of the table or inserting new rows into the table.

I have been successful (thanks in no small part to [JasonPlutext](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61075462/13242118)) with writing new cell contents to existing cells as well as creating entirely new cells/rows. I'd rather not have to write the header row and all the data rows first and them make it into a table using the API, but I would like to know if anybody know how it *should* be done. In the past, I could just create the table with the number of rows I knew I would need but in this case the rows quantity is dynamic. I was hoping I could just reference a tablePart and then there would be some method for inserting into a List object.

Any guidance is appreciated.

EDIT:

So as a concrete example, let's say I have a workbook and sheet with an existing table of 2 columns with 2 rows (including the header) starting at A1. I can open the underlying xl>tables>table1.xml and see this:

```xml
    <table xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="xr xr3" xmlns:xr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2014/revision" xmlns:xr3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2016/revision3" id="5" xr:uid="{FAABA541-34FC-423B-94F5-DDD8D784132E}" name="SummarySFTP" displayName="SummarySFTP" ref="A1:B2" totalsRowShown="0" headerRowDxfId="46" headerRowBorderDxfId="45" tableBorderDxfId="44">
        <autoFilter ref="A1:B2" xr:uid="{93499C15-75FB-4436-A9B9-0C1FCBD787F4}">
            <filterColumn colId="0" hiddenButton="0"/>
            <filterColumn colId="1" hiddenButton="0"/>
        </autoFilter>
        <tableColumns count="2">
            <tableColumn id="1" xr3:uid="{D4DA50CD-C581-4286-9B64-42B02B6646B6}" name="Status"/>
            <tableColumn id="2" xr3:uid="{9D4F40B3-B530-42E1-92E9-86D5632CA191}" name="Quantity" dataDxfId="43"/>
        </tableColumns>
        <tableStyleInfo showFirstColumn="0" showLastColumn="0" showRowStripes="1" showColumnStripes="0"/>
    </table>
```

I can see my two columns, and the ref attribute of the root  tag as well as the autoFilter block's ref attribute. What I want to do is add a new row such that the area of the table would be A1:B3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspecting an xlsx file containing a table in the docx4j webapp, it looks fairly straightforward.

It generates code for the contents of the table part like:

```
CTTable table = smlObjectFactory.createCTTable(); 
JAXBElement<org.xlsx4j.sml.CTTable> tableWrapped = smlObjectFactory.createTable(table); 
    // Create object for autoFilter
    CTAutoFilter autofilter = smlObjectFactory.createCTAutoFilter(); 
    table.setAutoFilter(autofilter); 
        autofilter.setRef( "A2:B4"); 
    // Create object for tableColumns
    CTTableColumns tablecolumns = smlObjectFactory.createCTTableColumns(); 
    table.setTableColumns(tablecolumns); 
        tablecolumns.setCount( new Long(2) );
        // Create object for tableColumn
        CTTableColumn tablecolumn = smlObjectFactory.createCTTableColumn(); 
        tablecolumns.getTableColumn().add( tablecolumn); 
            tablecolumn.setTotalsRowFunction(org.xlsx4j.sml.STTotalsRowFunction.NONE);
            tablecolumn.setName( "Column1"); 
            tablecolumn.setId( 1 );
        // Create object for tableColumn
        CTTableColumn tablecolumn2 = smlObjectFactory.createCTTableColumn(); 
        tablecolumns.getTableColumn().add( tablecolumn2); 
            tablecolumn2.setTotalsRowFunction(org.xlsx4j.sml.STTotalsRowFunction.NONE);
            tablecolumn2.setName( "Column2"); 
            tablecolumn2.setId( 2 );
    // Create object for tableStyleInfo
    CTTableStyleInfo tablestyleinfo = smlObjectFactory.createCTTableStyleInfo(); 
    table.setTableStyleInfo(tablestyleinfo); 
        tablestyleinfo.setName( "TableStyleMedium2"); 
    table.setTableType(org.xlsx4j.sml.STTableType.WORKSHEET);
    table.setHeaderRowCount( new Long(1) );
    table.setTotalsRowCount( new Long(0) );
    table.setName( "Table1"); 
    table.setId( 1 );
    table.setRef( "A2:B4"); 
    table.setDisplayName( "Table1");
```

Once you know the row quantity, you can see you need to write it in 2 places, using setRef and autofilter.setRef

Comment: Jason, thanks for the response. I have edited my original question above to include specifics. If I use Docx4J to open an existing workbook as described, are you saying that I will need to update both the table ref Attribute as well as the autofilter Attribute? I think I attempted before to update the table's ref attribute but not the autofilter.

Comment: Got around to testing this today and again, Jason, you were extremely helpful. If you are adding rows to an existing table and need to resize it, you must update the ref entries for both the table and the autofilter. As your response was for generating a new table from scratch I am including the code I used to update these entries in an existing table.

Comment: Here is how I did it:

```
table = xlsxPkg.getParts().get(new Packages.org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.PartName("/xl/tables/table1.xml")).getContents();
table.setRef( "A1:B3" );
table.getAutoFilter().setRef( "A1:B3" );
```